# Why isn't this custom element centered vertically?

Tags: css, flexbox, web-component, display, custom-element

EDIT:

Per the comments, it was unexpected that the `<div>` was *ever* centering - turned out to be a height thing, where the `<div>` was taking up the parent's full height, but the custom element's children were not.

Also this isn't a duplicate but whatever

---

I have the following css:

```
.layout-main {
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

If I do the following:

```
<div class="layout-main">
  <div> stuff goes here </div>
</div>
```

,

the "stuff" is centered vertically.

However, if I define a custom element, which results in:

```
<div class="layout-main">
  <my-element>
    <div> stuff goes here </div>
  </my-element>
</div>
```

the "stuff" is *not* centered vertically.

If I explicitly set `justify-content: center` on `.layout-main`, problem solved.

If I set `display: contents` on `my-element`, problem also solved.

Saw [this](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/723) that seemed related / [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-box) on `contents`

Why is the custom element not centered vertically the way a div is when inside a `display: flex; justify-content: center` parent?

Comment: There's no reason for the `div` in your first example to be centered vertically. The rest of your post makes sense. The original `div` should not be centered vertically, based on the code you're providing here.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin that's interesting... let me take another look at my code

Answer (score 1):

The `display: flex` property will only change the positioning of its children, not its children's children. It would be best if you moved the class="layout-main" part onto the my-element block and then set it's height to be 100% of it's parent div's height.